# Se deshabilita evento click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tengo varios `div` con botones los cuales tienen el evento de eliminar el nodo cada vez que se de `click` en ellos, o sea un `click` elimina el nodo en el que están, el primer problema que se da `click` una vez y luego se elimina el evento de los nodos que quedan, ahora el segundo problema es cuando se crean nodos no obtiene el evento.

```
let btnEliminar = document.querySelector('.idEliminar')
btnEliminar.addEventListener('click', eliminarUsuario, false)
function eliminarUsuario (evento) {
  let _id = evento.target.getAttribute('idAttr')
  let opcion = confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar?")
  if (opcion) {
    let nodo = document.querySelector(`#usuario-${cortarCadena(_id)}`)
    nodo.parentNode.removeChild(nodo)
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que estás asociando el evento de manera correcta? Tal y como está el código, sólo se va a asociar al primer elemento con clase `.idEliminar` y no a los demás (porque estás usando `querySelector` en lugar de `querySelectorAll`, además de que no se está iterando para asociar el controlador de evento).

Answer (score 1):

Existen varios problemas con esto... pero básicamente puedes ciclar de manera tradicional obteniendo tus elementos por clases o tags para agregarle el evento a cada coincidencia en el DOM.

Esto está pasando porque estas seleccionando tus elementos con `querySelector`, esto solo te agregará el evento al primer elemento que coincida, puedes utilizar `querySelectorAll` o como explico en el ejemplo en todo caso. Como adicional no especifiques el argumento useCapture.

```js
let btnEliminar = document.getElementsByTagName('button')

for (var i=0; i < btnEliminar.length; i++) {
  btnEliminar[i].addEventListener('click', eliminarUsuario)
}

function eliminarUsuario(e) {
  let _id = e.target.value;
  console.log(_id)
  let opcion = confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar?")
  if (opcion) {
     let nodo = document.getElementById(_id)
     nodo.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<button value="id1">Eliminar id1</button>
<div id="id1">
  <p>Este div tiene la id id1</p>
</div>

<button value="id2">Eliminar id2</button>
<div id="id2">
  <p>Este div tiene la id id2</p>
</div>

<button value="id3">Eliminar id3</button>
<div id="id3">
  <p>Este div tiene la id id3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te pasa es que no estás obteniendo los nuevos cambios de los nodos y entonces no les agregás el listener al evento. A continuación te dejo dos opciones, una con jQuery (es más sencillo y más si recién estás empezando con javascript) y la otra es con javascript puro que es similar a lo que hace.

### Usando jQuery con [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
// esto es para ejecutar todo lo que esté por dentro una vez
// que cargue el DOM
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $('.idEliminar') -> obtiene los elementos con este selector
  // .on() -> para capturar el evento
  // el primer parámetro es el tipo de evento
  // el segundo es otro selector del nodo padre
  // el tercero es la función a ejecutar
  $('.idEliminar').on('click', '.parent-element', eliminarUsuario);

  function eliminarUsuario(evento) {
    let _id = evento.target.getAttribute('idAttr')
    let opcion = confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar?")
    if (opcion) {
    let nodo = document.querySelector(`#usuario-${cortarCadena(_id)}`)
    nodo.parentNode.removeChild(nodo)
    }
  }
});
```

### Usando javascript y generando una función similar al `.on()`

```
function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
  el.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
    var t = event.target;
    while (t && t !== this) {
      if (t.matches(sel)) {
        handler.call(t, event);
      }
      t = t.parentNode;
    }
  });
}

// uso de la función
delegate(document, 'click', '.parent-element', eliminarUsuario);

function eliminarUsuario(evento) {
  let _id = evento.target.getAttribute('idAttr')
  let opcion = confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar?")
  if (opcion) {
  let nodo = document.querySelector(`#usuario-${cortarCadena(_id)}`)
  nodo.parentNode.removeChild(nodo)
  }
}
```

Fuente de [Javascript equivalent to $.on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880807/8968285)